# WorkManager chaining work without knowing what work request user will make

Tags: android, android-workmanager

So, I have the following use case:

- User can create a new Unit (model).
- Then user can do Unit Inspection (model) for that Unit.
- The issue is that user is not forced to do Unit Inspection after Unit. They can just create a new Unit and skip Unit Inspection.

So, I do not know how to create Work Manager chain for this, since I do not know work graph upfront.

Basically it is for technician that can Unit Inspections like flat, house, etc and in the app while they are offline they can create a new unit and then do unit inspection for that unit. When that happens, I need first send unit to the API to get the response and then send another API request to save Unit Inspection. But, they also can only create a new unit in the offline and for some reason decide to not do unit inspection.

So, I need execute Unit API request, then wait for the response and after I get success then I need to execute Unit Inspection request, if exists.

Any ideas?